# Updating Android tools inside of SDK Manager automatically restarts my machine

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is what's going on... It doesn't matter if I'm in Eclipse or manually launch SDK Manager. Once I'm in the Android SDK Manager I have packages selected and I click Install x packages... I accept the License agreement then click Install. It is then my computer restarts itself before it downloads and installs anything. It restarts before I can see any error messages. It does this every single time. I have re-downloaded everything and tried it from scratch, but I still get it. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent it?!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I would uninstall everything and do a fresh install.

Comment: Running Windows 7-64 bit. A co-worker is running the same system setup I am and has no issues. I've done an uninstall everything and fresh install with an exception to reinstalling windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody on here could help me I figured it out. Here's what I did. First, I gave all permissions and took away read only attributes for the folder sdk [it may be named something different on your system] I then created a copy of the tools folder and named it tools 2. I opened a command prompt using administrator and use the command "android.bat avd manager" and i was able to update my sdk tools and all without any issues. Thank you me.